# problema con sequelize para hacer un query del rating

Tags: postgresql, datatables, sequelize

me gustaría si me pudieran asistir con mi problema intento hacer un average para sacar el promedio y no me funciona, si pueden decirme qué está mal, se los agradecería. Básicamente lo que intento es que me haga el average de las stars y con en findAndCountAll que me las cuente automáticamente para el número de reviews.

El modelo en cuestión es:

```
const Review = sequelize.define('Review', {

    stars: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    comment: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  },{
    tableName: 'review',
  });
};
```

mis relaciones son:

```
Review.belongsTo(User);
User.hasMany(Review);

Review.belongsTo(Product);
Product.hasMany(Review);
```

y mi consulta es

```
server.get('/:id/review', (req, res, next) => {
  const productId = req.params.id
  Review.findAndCountAll({ 
    where: {productId: productId},
    attributes: ["id", "stars", "comment", "productId", "userId", 
      [
        Sequelize.fn("avg", Sequelize.col("reviews.stars")),
        "averageRating"
      ]
    ]
  })
  .then(result => {...}
```